# Session Cookie Not Saving On Browser

Tags: express, graphql, express-session

I am using the code in this repo:
[prisma-cookies](https://github.com/benawad/prisma-cookies)

Everything seems to work however, the session cookie is not being saved on my browser when I test the server using graphql playground. In other words, I send a login mutation to the server, the login clearly works however no cookie is saved on the browser.

I am running a GraphQL Yoga server on ExpressJS on NodeJS.

Please let me know if you need me to add any additional information. 

Your help is greatly appreciated!

index.ts

```
import { GraphQLServer } from "graphql-yoga";
import * as session from "express-session";
import { Prisma } from "./generated/prisma";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";

const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: "./src/schema.graphql",
  resolvers,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    db: new Prisma({
      endpoint: process.env.PRISMA_ENDPOINT, // the endpoint of the Prisma DB service (value is set in .env)
      secret: process.env.PRISMA_SECRET, // taken from database/prisma.yml (value is set in .env)
      debug: true // log all GraphQL queries & mutations
    })
  })
});

const SESSION_SECRET = "lsdfjlkjlkewaqra";

server.express.use(
  session({
    name: "qid",
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 7 days
    }
  })
);

const cors = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
};

server.start({ cors }, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:4000`)
);
```

auth.ts

```
import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { Context } from "../../utils";

export const auth = {
  async signup(parent, args, ctx: Context, info) {
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10);
    const user = await ctx.db.mutation.createUser({
      data: { ...args, password }
    });

    ctx.request.session.userId = user.id;

    return {
      user
    };
  },

  async login(parent, { email, password }, ctx: Context, info) {
    const user = await ctx.db.query.user({ where: { email } });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error(`No such user found for email: ${email}`);
    }

    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!valid) {
      throw new Error("Invalid password");
    }

    ctx.request.session.userId = user.id;

    return {
      user
    };
  }
};
```

util.ts

```
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { Prisma } from "./generated/prisma";

export interface Context {
  db: Prisma;
  request: any;
}

export function getUserId(ctx: Context) {
  if (ctx.request.session.userId) {
    return ctx.request.session.userId;
  }

  throw new AuthError();
}

export class AuthError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super("Not authorized");
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

So there is actually a bug in graphql playground at the moment. I spent about 12 hours overt the past 2 days trying to figure out what the issue was. The issue is that Graphql Playground isn't sending the credentials with your request. Theoretically you should be able to click the settings icon in the upper right and change your "credentials" to "include", but they will still be sent as "omit".

https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground/issues/826